# Recover document.xml from a corrupt docx

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, file-corruption

I've got a Word document(docx) which is corrupt, when I open it up in Word I am presented with a dialog that tells me that it needs to bo repaird but the reparation fails.

Then I tried extracting the files with WinRAR but I'm getting CRC errors.

So I tried going for only `document.xml`, which seem to be the only file that is corrupt, but even if I select to `keep broken files` when extracting with WinRAR, the result filesize is `0`.

Is there anything else to try more than this? Can this document be saved?

Answer (score 1):

As an update I found the DOCX2TXT software at http://www.downloadatlas.com/freeware-f4b1bc35.html.  However, you have to jump through several hoops and download other programs to get it.  Be very aware on this site.  They try to trick you into downloading anything and everything.  It's a real hassle but I finally got it.
And I must say, it worked exptremely well.  I recovered all 33 documents.  The only problem was that you have to open and close the program before each file, which took me about an hour to accomplish. Perhaps an update will privide for a CLOSE instead of just OPEN, SAVE, and EXIT.  Best of luck!